# Apple Mail app search bar

Tags: ipad, mail.app

This may seem like a strange request (and I really hope it doesn't get closed) but I need some info on the iPad Mail app as I don't have an iPad.
On the inbox there is a search box at the top, if you scroll down a bit and then scroll up fast so that the table bounces. I need to know if the search box bounces with the table or if it sticks to the navigation bar at the top.

If this question is considered off topic, then please don't close it, I'll delete the question after an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search bar sticks to the top of the mail items and "bounces" with them when scrolled past the top.